# Excel if statement parameters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two individual statements that work individually

```
=IF(C6=1,(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(C4,list1,IF(C5"apple",2,IF(C5="orange",3,
IF(C5="plum",4,IF(C5="grape",5,IF(C5="banana",6,"")))))),"")))
```

and

```
=IF(C6=2,(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(C4,list2,IF(C5"apple",2,IF(C5="orange",3,
IF(C5="plum",4,IF(C5="grape",5,IF(C5="banana",6,"")))))),"")))
```

But when i combine them both into if statements,

```
=IF(C6=1,(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(C4,list1,IF(C5="apple",2,IF(C5="orange",3,
IF(C5="plum",4,IF(C5="grape",5,IF(C5="banana",6,"")))))),""))),

IF(C6=2,(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(C4,list2,IF(C5="apple",2,IF(C5="orange",3,
IF(C5="plum",4,IF(C5="grape",5,IF(C5="banana",6,"")))))),"")))
```

The Data Look like this

[Data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFvsp.png)

I get a '#Value!' Error, parentheses seem to be in place, not sure whats yielding this error.

Comment: You have `IF(C6=2, ... List1, ...` and `IF(C6=2, ... List2, ...` . Which is it? Are you sure you want HLOOKUP to match approximate (sorted) and not exact (FALSE)?

Comment: I edited the formula.  HLOOKUP should work in this case, i just want it to match with the correct cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you need to do some reading on the [HLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-f3f3b210-5dd6-4b58-9c83-b9db2c306d6a), [LOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lookup-function-df82ce98-edf9-46ea-8189-b0470e5e0e93) amd [CHOOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHOOSE-function-fce63190-b514-48cc-a7ff-c1cdaaec0907).

This formula follows the rules of your sample formula(s) (such as they are) and should serve to simplify matters by avoiding repetition. Note that `"apple","banana","grape","orange","plum"` are in alphabetical order.

```
=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(C4, CHOOSE(C6, List1, List2, List1),
                     LOOKUP(C5, {"apple","banana","grape","orange","plum"}, {2,6,5,3,4}),
                     FALSE), "")
```

If you require more assistance, please edit your original question to include sample data and expected results.

Comment: I just want to combine my two if statements. If the drop down answer(c6) is 1 use List1, if the drop down answer(c6) is 2 use List2.